# Accelerator for Button in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have an app in JavaFX with .FXML file and i add a button to the scene. Then i tried to add accelerator to it but when it launches it throws NullPointerException. Why it doesn't work and how to solve this.

```
  @FXML
    Button addQuickNote;

    @FXML
    public void handlequickNote(ActionEvent e) {
        String text = SampleController.getSelectedText();
        if (text != null) {
            SampleController.profileManager.insertNote(DataParser.getNote(text));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        addQuickNote.getScene().getAccelerators().put(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.Q, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN), new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                addQuickNote.fire();
            }
        });
    }
```

My .fxml is pretty complicated because it contains whole module for my app so i paste  only a line with the button. The button is placed in the ToolBar.

```
<Button fx:id="addQuickNote" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handlequickNote" prefWidth="77.0" text="Z tekstu" />
```

I'm loading .fxml as a part of main scene.  I'm doing this by this code.

```
try {
    panel = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Notes.fxml"));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    showErrorDialog ....;
}
rightPanel.getChildren().add(panel);
mainPanel.setRight(rightPanel);
```

Comment: Can you show your .fxml also?

Comment: Make sure that the addQuickNote is linked as the Button fx:id in your FXML file

Comment: addQuickNote is linked as the Button fx:id in FXML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that `addQuickNote.getScene()` is `null` because your controls are not fully initialized at this point and the Button just has no `Scene` set.

Solve this by not calling `addQuickNote.getScene().getAccelerators()...` in the `initialize` method. After your Controller-initialization in your `main`-method do another call to your controller to a method in which you are initialize your accelerators.

---

EDIT:
Your `start` method seems to be incomplete. It have to look something like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("MainScene.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(page);
    MainSceneController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.initializeAccelerators();

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: I've tested the solution but i still have the same exception. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I'm loading .fxml as a part of main scene. See code in question.

Answer (score 4):

As user714965 mentionend your Scene was not constructed fully yet and therefor `addQuickNote.getScene()` is `null`.
Another solution might be something like this:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {        
        addQuickNote.getScene().getAccelerators().put(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.Q, KeyCombination.SHORTCUT_DOWN), () -> {
            addQuickNote.fire();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I like this solution the best of all presented (here and in other threads)

Comment: It's a little "hacky" though by using Platform.runLater()

Comment: @Denis don't rely on runLater - the exact time of running is unspecified! Instead, listen to sceneProperty of the node and install everything scene-related in that listener